# Join 2 Lookup Tables to a Detail table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, reporting-services

I have 3 tables:

- Products
- Groups
- Sales

The products table contains the following information:

```
|**Product ID**|**Product Description**|
|--------------|-----------------------|
|1             |Wine                   |
|2             |Ruler                  |
|3             |Gas                    |
|4             |Water                  |
```

The Groups table contains the following information:

```
|**Group ID**|**Group Description**|
|------------|---------------------|
|1           |Cheetahs             |
|2           |Elephants            |
|3           |Cougars              |
```

The Sales table contains the following information:

```
|**GroupID**|**Product ID**|**Amount Sold**|**Day Sold**|
|-----------|--------------|---------------|------------|
|1          |2             |              3|07-31-2016  |
|1          |1             |              1|07-31-2016  |
|2          |3             |              5|07-31-2016  |
|1          |4             |              2|08-01-2016  |
```

Now I have to produce a query that could bring me a result set as follows (with the condition that I want only results from 07-31-2016):

```
|**Group ID**|**Product ID**|**Amount Sold**|
|------------|--------------|---------------|
|1           |1             |1              |
|1           |2             |3              |
|1           |3             |0              |
|1           |4             |0              |
|2           |1             |0              |
|2           |2             |0              |
|2           |3             |5              |
|2           |4             |0              |
|3           |1             |0              |
|3           |2             |0              |
|3           |3             |0              |
|3           |4             |0              |
```

I thought this was going to be just a matter of using left joins, but it appears it wouldn't bring me back the result I was looking for (I don't want to omit products nor groups which weren't sold).

So in summary, I need to display all groups and all products no matter if they had an appearance in the Sales table.

I would appreciate any feedback on this matter, directions on where to look at or any logic that I may be missing!

---

### EDIT

I've marked **Matt's** (big thanks) post as the answer, turns out I've never used a cross join.

I only added the where clause inside the left join of the Sales table in order to get just the sales made on 07-31-2016

```
SELECT
    g.GroupId
    ,p.ProductId
    ,SUM(COALESCE(s.AmountSold,0)) as AmountSold
FROM
    Products p
    CROSS JOIN Groups g
    LEFT JOIN Sales s
    ON p.ProductId = s.ProductId
    AND g.GroupId = s.GroupId
    AND daySold = '07-31-2016'
GROUP BY
    g.GroupId
    ,p.ProductId
ORDER BY
    g.GroupId
    ,p.ProductId
```

Comment: you just need to create a Cartesian join between products and groups then left join your sales to it.  this can be done with a cross join

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: It's not homework, and it's not the original problem, I'm using this as a reference to solve another situation

Comment: @Matt thanks, I've never used Cross joins, I'll look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    g.GroupId
    ,p.ProductId
    ,SUM(COALESCE(s.AmountSold,0)) as AmountSold
FROM
    Products p
    CROSS JOIN Groups g
    LEFT JOIN Sales s
    ON p.ProductId = s.ProductId
    AND g.GroupId = s.GroupId
    AND s.daySold = '07-31-2016'
GROUP BY
    g.GroupId
    ,p.ProductId
ORDER BY
    g.GroupId
    ,p.ProductId
```

Note your expected results you provided are wrong for group 1 product 4 there were 2 of those in the sale.

Comment: I need to extract all the sales from 07-31-2016, and when I do it will just bring me back the sales made on that day and disregard the other groups and products, that's why I skipped that group, because it's not supposed to be included in my result set

Answer (score 1):

You could join all the Products with all the Groups (so you get a list of all the combinations of the two) and then add the additional information (filtering out the results based on your condition with a `WHERE` statement.

```
SELECT A.[Group ID]
     , B.[Product ID]
     , ISNULL([Amount Sold], 0) AS 'Amount Sold'
FROM Groups A
INNER JOIN Products B
ON 1 = 1
LEFT JOIN Sales C
ON C.[Group ID] = A.[Group ID]
AND C.[Product ID] = B.[Product ID]
WHERE [Day Sold] = '07-31-2016'
```